# When cloning my edited forked git repository the changes are not reflected and original repository is cloned instead

Tags: python, git, github, git-clone, git-fork

my goal is to fork an original repository,edit it, and then clone it on my beaglebone black.

Here are the links to the existing repositories:
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_BNO055
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO

Here are the links to my edited forked version of the repositories:
https://github.com/frank2597/Adafruit_Python_BNO055
https://github.com/frank2597/Adafruit_Python_GPIO

I made a few changes...
in Adafruit_Python_GPIO/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py i changed the I2C bus to 2 on line 55:

```
return 2
```

in Adafruit_Python_GPIO/setup.py i changed line 32 to:

```
url = 'https://github.com/frank2597/Adafruit_Python_GPIO/',
```

in Adafruit_Python_BNO055/setup.py i changed lines 27 and 28 to:

```
url = 'https://github.com/frank2597/Adafruit_Python_BNO055/',

dependency_links =['https://github.com/frank2597/Adafruit_Python_GPIO/tarball/master#egg=Adafruit-GPIO-0.9.3'],
```

then i cloned Adafruit_Python_BNO055 and installed the dependency Adafruit_Python_GPIO with setup.py:

```
git clone https://github.com/frank2597/Adafruit_Python_BNO055.git
cd Adafruit_Python_BNO055
sudo python setup.py install
```

However unzipping the Adafruit_GPIO-1.0.4-py2.7.egg file and looking into the I2C.py file which is located here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_GPIO-1.0.4-py2.7.egg/Adafruit_GPIO/GPIO.pyc
```

i noticed that my changes have not been reflected and the I2C bus is still set to 1. It seems its still cloning the original repository and not my edited forked version. Does anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dependency_links` were declared obsolete and finally [removed](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) in `pip` 19.0. The replacement for it is `install_requires` with special syntax (supported since `pip` 19.1):

```
install_requires=[
    'package_name @ git+https://gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git@<COMMIT_ID>'
]
```

See https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references

This requires `pip install` including `pip install .` and doesn't work with `python setup.py install`.

In your particular case this means that `Adafruit_Python_BNO055/setup.py` ignores `dependency_links` and installs `Adafruit-GPIO` from PyPI. The solution is to remove `dependency_links` completely and install dependency `Adafruit-GPIO` using `pip` with `install_requires` in `setup.py`:

```
install_requires=[
    'Adafruit-GPIO @ git+https://github.com/frank2597/Adafruit_Python_GPIO',
    'pyserial',
]
```